# How to setup GLFW with eclipse c++ and MinGW compiler?

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, mingw, glfw

How do I include `glfw.h` and link the libraries `libglfw.a` and `libglfadll.a` in eclipse juno c++ with MinGW compiler. This is an attempt I made on setting it up:

[image]

This is the build command I tried to use:

`g++ -o Practice.exe "src\\main.o" "-lC:\\Users\\Kaiden.ZEUS\\Files" & "Folders\\Programming\\C++\\Workspaces\\Practice\\Practice\\lib\\libglfw.a" "-lC:\\Users\\Kaiden.ZEUS\\Files" &     "Folders\\Programming\\C++\\Workspaces\\Practice\\Practice\\lib\\libglfwdll.a"`

Answer (score 3):

Nothing of this is specific to OpenGL or GLEW, you're dealing with basic programmer craftsmanship skills here: How to configure a compiler linker toolchain to use additional libraries. This is essential knowledge, so please take the patience to properly learn it. The following is just a short list of notes what you should change. But you should really take up some learning material on the compilation and linking process to understand it.

---

You should place the libraries and headers into system wide directories, *but not* the standard directories of the compiler suite and configure those as additional search paths for the compiler and linker.

*DO NOT* put 3rd party library and header files into your project source tree, unless you take proper precautions that it won't interfere with likely installed systemwide instances of them.

Also you must choose between the static or the dynamically linked version of GLFW. If you use both you'll get symbol conflicts (this is something specific to GLFW).

In your build command line you're using the -l`option with *directories*. This is wrong, search paths are specified using`-L`(capital L), while`-l`(lower l) just specifies library names without the path, prefix and suffix. Also you can replace backslashes`` with forward slashes `/`, saving you some typing, i.e. the `\\` escaping to produce a single backslashe to the command. In your case (I shortened the path)

```
g++ -o Practice.exe "src/main.o" "-LC:/Users/Kaiden.ZEUS/Files/ ... /lib" "-lglfw"
```

or

```
g++ -o Practice.exe "src/main.o" "-LC:/Users/Kaiden.ZEUS/Files/ ... /lib" "-lglfwdll"
```

However this compile command lacks specification of the include files. Say you've got the GLEW headers installed in `C:/Users/Kaiden.ZEUS/Files/ ... /include/GL` you'd add

```
"-IC:/Users/Kaiden.ZEUS/Files/ ... /include/GL"
```

to the command line.